# want to get username from SC.get() function of soundcloud api

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

**i want to get the the username of the soundcloud after he succesfully get connected to the soundcloud...i am able to get connected but not getting the username of soundcloud user**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
      SC.initialize({
          client_id: '****',
          redirect_uri: '***'
      });

  $('#connect').click(function(){
          SC.connect(function() {
              SC.get('/me', function(data) {
                  $('#name').text(data.username);
              });
          });
      });
  });

  </script>

</head>

<body>

<input type="image" src="images/larger-connect-with-sc.png" id="connect" />
<p>
Logged in as: <span id="name"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Can you try debugging the response from the API? See what is being returned by looking at the network request, and also the value of `data` in your callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<body onload="window.opener.setTimeout(window.opener.SC.connectCallback, 1)"> <b style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">This popup should automatically close in a few seconds</b> </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks okay to me. Here's some trimmed down, but complete source code that you can use to compare against:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Example Two</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    SC.initialize({
      client_id: '8d720a0f46531b275c7c9a82619c9d46',
      redirect_uri: 'http://demo.paulosman.me/callback.html'
    });

    $('#connect').click(function() {
      SC.connect(function() {
        SC.get('/me', function(data) {
          $('#name').text(data.username);
        });
      });
    });
  });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="image" src="images/larger-connect-with-sc.png" id="connect" />
    <p>
      Logged in as: <span id="name"></span>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can see a working example [here](http://demo.paulosman.me/connect.html).

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks Paul for answering ... but when the pop-menu get's closed how do i refresh the connect.html page itself...like you doing...tell me about callback.html file..what you have done there??

Comment: okk i got that thanks i was mistaken in callback file...i didn't use SC.connectCallback function ...

Comment: Hello Paul Osman, I am using the same code you mentioned above. I am getting the soundcloud authentication pop window but after i enter my email and password and click connect i am getting a popup window showing "This popup should automatically close in a few seconds" but its not getting closed. Please help me out. Thanks in advance :)